# pthread_cond_broadcast before and after one pthread_mutex_unlock

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex

For the code below, the mutex will not available by the time second cond_broadcast is executed(assuming multiple threads already waiting on the condition). In such situation, does the broadcast select the thread(waiting on the condition) to hand the mutex to and wait for the mutex to be unlocked by some other thread or the second cond_broadcast is just ignored?

```
void* func(void* arg){
pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
while(condition){
pthread_cond_wait(&c,&m);
}
pthread_cond_broadcast(&c);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
pthread_cond_broadcast(&c);
}
```

Comment: The broadcast will only be noticed by threads that are waiting on the condition at the moment of the broadcast.  You'd normally signal/broadcast while holding the mutex, then release it.. and waiting threads should only wait when they hold the mutex, after checking the condition.  They should also signal the condition before releasing the mutex if any other thread could be waiting.

Comment: Calling `pthread_cond_broadcast()` when you don't have the mutex will still do the broadcast, but it could be missed if a thread has the mutex but isn't waiting on the condition at the moment of the broadcast, so it's not good to do it that way.  Signalling only while the mutex is locked ensures that the signal can't be sent while another thread holds the mutex unless that thread is waiting for the signal.

Comment: Thank you! Just a follow up question: Is it possible to have two threads waiting on same condition but different mutex eg. pthread_cond_wait(&c,&m1) and pthread_cond_wait(&c,&m2)? If possible, then will pthread_cond_broadcast(&c) from third thread wake both the threads and will they acquire mutex concurrently(assuming no other thread exists)?

Comment: It's possible, but not a good idea.  If the condition variable isn't consistently used with a single mutex, you can't ensure that signals won't be missed.  And if you use two mutexes and lock both when signalling, you risk deadlocks.  The mutex ensures signals are only sent when the threads that listen for them are either in the `pthread_cond_wait()` call, or not holding the mutex (and presumably don't care about the condition at that time).

Comment: Nothing prevents you from using different mutexes, but the program won't (reliably) work if you do.  Using the same mutex is what keeps the signals and waits synchronized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For the code below, the mutex will not available by the time second
> cond_broadcast is executed(assuming multiple threads already waiting
> on the condition).

I think you mean that the mutex will not be available to the thread calling `pthread_cond_broadcast()` at the second call to that function, but that's irrelevant.  Calling `pthread_cond_broadcast()` is independent of holding any mutex.

Or perhaps you mean that one of the previously blocked threads will have acquired the mutex by the time the second broadcast happens, but (1) that's not certain, and (2) if it does happen, that has no particular significance with respect to the broadcast.

> In such situation, does the broadcast select the
> thread(waiting on the condition) to hand the mutex to and wait for the
> mutex to be unlocked by some other thread or the second cond_broadcast
> is just ignored?

Neither.  `pthread_cond_broadcast()` and `pthread_cond_signal()` have no role in locking or transferring control of any mutex.  They just wake threads blocked on the associated CV.  That each such thread must acquire the mutex before returning from the call is a separate consideration -- they all contend normally to lock the mutex, and they do not return from `pthread_cond_wait()` until they do.  They also do not go back to waiting without first returning from their wait and then calling `pthread_cond_wait()` again.

But that does not mean that the second `pthread_cond_broadcast()` in your code necessarily will have no effect.  One of the just-woken threads might loop around and wait on the CV again between the two calls, or some other thread might arrive at the CV.  That becomes possible as soon as the first thread releases the mutex, and the fact that the first thing that thread tries to do is another broadcast does not ensure that the broadcast happens before another thread can start waiting.

It is unlikely that you want two broadcasts one after the other like that, but which one you retain has little, if any, effect on the overall semantics of the program.